# SignalR C# Client not calling a method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I created a server with SignalR and SQLTableDependency. After that, I created a project with Vue and SignalR Javascript Client and everything works, the notification subscription in the server execute a SignalR method to send the object to all the Clients

```
private void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Todo> eventArgs)
    {
        if(eventArgs.ChangeType != TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.None)
        {
            var changedEntity = eventArgs.Entity;
            var mensaje = TipoCambios(eventArgs);
            _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("RegistrarTarea", changedEntity);
        }
    }
```

In JavaScript Client I made this:

```
coneccionTodo.on("RegistrarTarea", todos => {
    this.$refs.alerta.Abrir(todos.cambio, "info", "Alerta");
    console.log(todos);
  });
  coneccionTodo
    .start()
    .then(response => {
      this.sinConexion = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error Todo SignalR", error.toString());
    });
```

The result of that is this:

[image]

And finally my C# Client made with .Net Core 2.1. This is not working

```
public static async Task Ejecutar() {
    connection.On<List<dynamic>>("RegistrarTarea", (objects) => {
        Console.WriteLine(objects);
    });
    try
    {                                
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine($"Conexión exitosa a {url}");
        await connection.StartAsync();
        //await connection.InvokeAsync("RegistrarTarea", "Consola", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SignalR_Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

In `void main` Console app I call the `Ejecutar` method:

```
    connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(url).Build();
    connection.Closed += async (error) => {
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
        await connection.StartAsync();
    };
    Task.Run(() => Ejecutar());
    Console.ReadLine();
```

NOTE: In the server, the CORS are activated to allow anything.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Direct mode ? The direct mode does not function with this. Turn the Direct mode off.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in `connection.on` I use a List, but instead of that, I used a Class with the properties like the server send. So now, it's working:

```
    connection.On<Result>("RegistrarTarea", (result) => {                
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine(result.Cambio);
    });
```

[image]